# New WIn UI project crashes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winui-3

I have installed the winui extension to Visual Studio 19.  I created a new project using the Win UI desktop template.  I have built the two projects created (one is the package).  I try to run the project before adding any code and it immediately crashes at start up.  The error is
COMException: Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

The error occurs at the last line of this subroutine  (marked with **)

```
 public static class Program
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.Compiler"," 0.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.STAThreadAttribute]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            global::WinRT.ComWrappersSupport.InitializeComWrappers();
            **global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => {
                var context = new global::Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueueSynchronizationContext(global::Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread());**
                global::System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
                new App();
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm at a loss to fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.  with the help of this post
https://gitmemory.com/issue/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/5054/845542110

1. I need to deploy the solution.  (Go to solution properties, Configuration and check the build and deploy boxes.
2. Deploy the package application.
3. Set the package application to the Startup project.
4. run the project.